# How do I get the "Batman: Arkham City" retail patch?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I have the retail DVD version of Batman" Arkham City - it is not the Steam version and it cannot be activated on Steam.  How can I get the latest patch ("DirectX 11 patch")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Batman: Arkham City patches via [Games For Windows Live](http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/showthread.php/11809-Where-do-those-who-purchased-the-game-through-Origin-get-this-patch) if you're not using Steam.  When you log into GFWL, you will be informed that a patch is available, and then it will be installed.

Note that just because a Steam patch is out, it doesn't mean that the same patch has hit GFWL; depending on the publisher/developer's release schedule, it may be delayed.

I would recommend being patient, and if you're having trouble, to go ask on the [official forums](http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/), where Rocksteady Community Managers are providing support.

This is the [official thread](http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/showthread.php/11700-Latest-PC-Update-Today-s-Patch-details) for the most recent patch.